# How to install Soundflower on Mac OS use Terminal?

Tags: macos, installation

Now I need to install Soundflower on mac, I download the source code from Github, then I opened "Terminal" to install it, but I had got some trouble.

First is, in "build.rb" file,

`sudo chown -R root #{@svn_root}/Build/InstallerRoot/System/Library/Extensions/Soundflower.kext`

this is a wrong for the real path "Build/InstallerRoot", it only have path named "InstallerRoot/Library/Extensions/Soundflower.kext"

Then, I try to drag "Soundflower.kext" to path "/System/Library/Extensions",
and run "sudo kextload -tv /System/Library/Extensions/Soundflower.kext", but I received the log:

`Notice: -print-diagnostics (-t) ignored; use kextutil(8) to test kexts.
Requesting load of /System/Library/Extensions/Soundflower.kext.
/System/Library/Extensions/Soundflower.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) not loadable (reason unspecified); check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).`

or, it got an alert like this:
`The system extension “/System/Library/Extensions/Soundflower.kext” was installed improperly and cannot be used……`

I can't fix it, and I can't find the path "`system/kernel logs`".

Someone can help me? Please..

Comment: Maybe try what it explains in the error message ("use kextutil ...").

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and it referred to 'com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower' , but I can't find it in anywhere, where is it?